# Declaring another alpha or beta testing after a game app for Android (APK file) is uploaded and already published in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-services, testing, release, deployment, beta

This question is related about alpha or beta release in Google Play Store. . Let's say my app (APK file) was uploaded in alpha/beta testing. If one of the testers satisfied or quick fixes on the bugs, then I'm gonna go promote to production, which means publishing an app. Now, let's say I wanna go for another alpha or beta testing for the next version before updating new version in production. I have to test it; let's say testing for the leaderboard or achievements created from the Game Services at Google Play Developers Console, adding Google Play Games plugins for *Unity* to the app, and then uploading the new APK version for the next beta release before updating new version in production. Is it possible or not?